# I don't know the name of a differential equation; How can I look up papers regarding it?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

I am interested in solutions to the differential equation

$$f(x)'' + (E + \frac{1}{4}x^2)f(x) = 0.$$

where $E$ is a constant.

This is slightly different from the much more common differential equation

$$f(x)'' + (E - \frac{1}{4}x^2)f(x) = 0,$$

that has the well known Weber functions as solutions.

I can be helped in one of two ways:

1. Do you know either the name or solution of this differential equation?
2. Is there a resource that allows you to search through papers for a specific differential equation?

Comment: [Solving a differential equation of the form $y''(x)+(b+ax^2)y(x)=0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1527290/solving-a-differential-equation-of-the-form-yxbax2yx-0) seems related (found by [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/)).

Comment: Might be worth your while to pick up a copy of this [standard reference](https://bookshop.org/books/ordinary-differential-equations-and-their-solutions/9780486485911).

Comment: This is a Parabolic Cylinder differential equation : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParabolicCylinderDifferentialEquation.html .